# Obtaining gain ratio with joint entropy

Tags: entropy

I want to normalize the information gain between two discrete random variables to obtain the gain ratio, as a unit invariant coefficient. is it an acceptable method to normalize the information gain with the joint entropy, as a shortcut to the intrinsic value, or do I have to do it according to the Wikipedia link below?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio

Many thanks!